# javascript or jquery error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have below code with jquery. Is jquery not working? I have two alertbox in javascript but second alertbox does not show and first alertbox show. No console errors.

```
    function validateForm(){
       alert("start of validateForm"); <-- this line show
        var errMsg = "";
        if ($("#accountName").val() == ""){
            $("#accountName").attr("class", "text_field text2 error_yellow");
            errMsg = errMsg + "<tld:label id="registration.step1.error.accountname" />";
        }
        else{
            $("#accountName").attr("class", "text_field text2");
        }
        alert("validateForm"); <-- Not going to this line
        ...................
    }

<s:form action="registration" method="post" id="registrationForm">

    <div class="field_input">
        <select name="registrationForm.accountName" 
        value="${registrationForm.accountName}"
        styleId="accountName" styleClass="text_field text2">
            <option value=""><tld:label id="reg1.request.detail14" /></option>
            <option
                value="<%=MembersiteConstant.MEMBER_ACCOUNT_TYPE_CREDIT_CARD%>"><tld:label id="registration.step1.option.card" /></option>
            <option
                value="<%=MembersiteConstant.MEMBER_ACCOUNT_TYPE_HP_PL%>"><tld:label id="registration.step1.option.loan" /></option>
        </select>
    </div>

<a id="a_btn_submit" href="javascript:validateForm()" class="formButton"><tld:label id="registration.button.next" /></a>
```

Comment: `Not going to this line` - "alert" has nothing to do with jQuery - check the browser **developer** tools console for any errors

Comment: Well what error does your console give you?

Comment: Why *should* it get to that line?  What's calling your `validateForm` function?

Comment: If it makes you feel any better, I've had this happen to me as well - no console errors, nothing helpful... code just wouldn't execute.  Can't remember how I solved it though, just lending some moral support. If you put the `alert` before the conditional block, does it work there?

Comment: I don't see the validateForm() function being called anywhere in the html you posted. Is this supposed to be called on a form submit?

Comment: sorry, I have added more code to demonstrate what I tested.

Comment: @AMMA: Ok, now what happens when you debug this code?  Open your browser's debugging tools and take a look at the development console.  Are there any errors?  When you step through the JavaScript code in the debugger, where does it fail?

Comment: Thanks David, Let me try.

Comment: Thanks David, it solved due to the some invalid path in the js.

Answer (score 1):

Your string isn't enclosed properly in this line:

```
errMsg = errMsg + "<tld:label id="registration.step1.error.accountname" />";
```

Try replacing it with:

```
errMsg = errMsg + "<tld:label id='registration.step1.error.accountname' />";
```

Or

```
errMsg = errMsg + "<tld:label id=\"registration.step1.error.accountname\" />";
```

**P.S:** As a pro tip always use your browser console to view JS error. Press `f12` in chrome or ie or ff to view browser console and then navigate to console menu to view JS errors